# Using an NSFormatter to alter string as user types

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstableview, nsnumberformatter

I'm writing a Mac OS X desktop Cocoa app. I've got an NSTableView with some values and I'm trying to control those values using a custom NSNumberFormatter.

My desired behavior:

As a user is typing a value, if they type -, I want it to behavior similar to a +/- button on a calculator. So if the user types "500-" then I want to automatically replace that string with "-500".

Now, I've got a working subclass of NSNumberFormatter which handles this situation and returns my desired replacement string. But when I'm typing into my NSTableView, my logs are showing me that "500-" is getting replaced with "-500" but the NSTableView only shows "500" and doesn't show the - either before OR after.

Is there something I need to do in my xib or in my NSNumberFormatter subclass so that the NSTableView will actually show the negative number?

```
- (BOOL) isPartialStringValid:(NSString **)partialStringPtr 
       proposedSelectedRange:(NSRangePointer)proposedSelRangePtr 
              originalString:(NSString *)origString 
       originalSelectedRange:(NSRange)origSelRange 
            errorDescription:(NSString **)error
```

is logging this to the console:

```
proposed string: 500-
replacement string: -500
```

But the cell in the NSTableView still shows just "500" afterward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that my old school C skills are just rusty and I wasn't passing the new string back correctly.

I was incorrectly writing:

```
partialStringPtr = &validString;
```

But the correct code is:

```
*partialStringPtr = validString;
```